# Storing a variable so that it is the same the next time the class is accessed

Tags: java, arrays, integer, increment

How do you store a variable so that when you're accessing a class, the variable is the same as before? In the main method the class is accessed once and I want to add the name to the array and increment _number and then when accessed again I want to add the next name into the incremented spot in the array. I read something about storing it as an object but couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance :)
This was my original code...

```
public void register(Object name) {
    _registered[_number] = name;
    _number++;
}
```

Comment: Read up about the `static` keyword.

Comment: ehm... I'm not clear on whether you are talking about a static variable, or a final one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than *describing* how you're calling this method, it would be really helpful if you could provide a [mcve] showing what you're trying to do, with the desired behavior vs the current behavior. At the moment it's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: As said above, can you paste your "main" methode code?

Comment: I assume you're asking about `_number`. Since `register()` is an instance method you'll need an instance to call the method on anyways. So I assume that `_registered` and `_number` need to be instance fields as well and thus as long as you are calling `register()` _on the same instance_ `_number` should increase. One thing though: instead of using an array I'd reccommend using a `List`. That way you'd probably not need `_number` at all.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions. Variable names are written in camelCase. That means no underscores.